# Cartthrob Subscriptions 5017 Rebill Sage Pay Error

Tags: cartthrob, subscriptions, sagepay

Have an installation of Cartthrob Subscriptions 2.6 installed and semi working with a SagePay Offsite test account which has token and repeat enabled and a continuous authority merchant number attached. I can successfully purchase a subscription using the Sage Pay test CC details, however when it comes to rebill the subscription the following error appears:

> The transaction was not registered because although the data sent to
>   the payment gateway was formatted correctly, some information supplied
>   was invalid. E.g. an incorrect vendor name or currency code was
>   sent.5017 : The Security Code(CV2) is required.

Anybody else seen this before with Sage Pay or have any ideas?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

yep I came across this bug too. Was a long time ago, and had hoped they would have fixed it by now, but here's what I did:

Open up /third_party/cartthrob/payment_gateways/Cartthrob_sage.php

**Bug #1**: 3DSecure check must be disabled for rebills, so find `'Apply3DSecure' => 0` and change the `0` to `2` (weird that it's not supposed to be zero, but there you go... You can see the values in [this ancient document](http://web.archive.org/web/20120521160505/http://www.docstoc.com/docs/10745827/Sage-Pay-Form-Protocol-and-Integration-Guidelines) p.38). On my old copy it's at line 379.

**Bug #2**: Then just after the $post_array variable is set (line 381 for me) we need to switch off the CVV2 check for rebills but keep it on for the initial transaction. [Buried deep in the old CT forums](http://cartthrob.com/forums/viewthread/5053/P150/#25639) is a solution as follows:

```
    if ($this->order('CVV2'))
    {
        $post_array['CV2'] = $this->order('CVV2');
    } else {
        $post_array['ApplyAVSCV2'] = 2;
    }
```